# How do I make vim with netbeans_intg?

Tags: vim

I don't see "netbeans_intg" in the vim Makefile, but I do see that I can configure vim with the feature `+netbeans_intg`, as documented [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#+netbeans_intg). I see that this feature is not included in the huge features install. The documentation for the netbeans feature says, "When running configure without arguments the NetBeans interface should be included.", and yet the output of `vim --version` shows `-netbeans-intg`.

```
./configure --help
```

shows

```
--enable-FEATURE[=ARG]  include FEATURE [ARG=yes]
```

but

```
./configure --enable-netbeans_intg=yes
```

prints

```
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-netbeans_intg
configure: loading cache auto/config.cache
configure: error: `CC' was set to `' in the previous run
configure: error: `CFLAGS' was set to `' in the previous run
configure: error: `LDFLAGS' was set to `' in the previous run
configure: error: `CPPFLAGS' was set to `' in the previous run
configure: error: in `/home/ros/vim/src':
configure: error: changes in the environment can compromise the build
configure: error: run `make distclean' and/or `rm auto/config.cache' and start over
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want this feature?

Doing `/netbeans` in `src/Makefile` jumps to this paragraph:

```
# NETBEANS - NetBeans interface. Only works with Motif, GTK, and gnome.
# Motif version must have XPM libraries (see |workshop-xpm|).
# Uncomment this when you do not want the netbeans interface.
#CONF_OPT_NETBEANS = --disable-netbeans
```

It sounds like the netbeans interface is compiled automatically if you compile Vim with a GUI. Which brings us back to my first question. And to this one: why do you want to compile Vim manually if a simple `$ sudo apt-get install vim-gnome` can bring you what you want?